# Why use the past perfect in "Theodora had been beautifully bred"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, past-perfect

The Apple dictionary defines the word "breed" and gives this example to show a meaning:

> Theodora had been beautifully bred.

I know the past perfect comes when there are two actions in the past, and  one of them happened before the other; yet in this example there is only one verb or one action.

So what does it indicate or how does the meaning here differ from the simple past tense ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context, context, context! Dictionaries haven't got room enough to provide context for all their example sentences; but in real life such sentences only occur in some context.

You ordinarily employ a past perfect in a narrative context—a novel, for instance, or a story or history, where the events all occur in your past. At any given point in the narrative you are talking about a particular past time, and you use the past perfect to bring in events which occurred **earlier** than that time.

In this case, for instance, which probably derives from a novel, it is likely that Theodora's breeding is brought into the story in order to provide background for a character making her first appearance, or to explain her behavior at the current moment in the story.

Comment: Many thanks for you Stoney,  I did not know about that dictionaries' problem before. Now it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: The  example hadn't been beautifully contextualized.